# QGIS PointConnector Plugin - x out of x lines not drawn

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, point, line

Unfortunately every try to generate lines between points (.shp) with ids (1-6) and a csv-file with from - to values failed. Maybe you can give me a hint whats wrong with my workflow?

1) I generated a point-shape with ids 1 to 6, no other column
2) I created a csv with this content (from, to)

```
1,2
3,2
4,2
5,2
6,2
```

[image: point_connector_issue]

Here's the plugin repo: https://github.com/peterahlstrom/PointConnector

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PointConnector is now updated to support integers as input, which should solve this issue. Please let me know if it doesn't!